# Creating Variables with Group in R igraph2

Tags: r, legend, igraph

in the link is my previous question and codes about igraph in R

[Creating Variables with Group in R igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625245/creating-variables-with-group-in-r-igraph)

My question now is why the arrow head in the example are small while mine are big like this:

[image]

How can I reshape the arrow to look like the answer on my previous question. I am using a mac.

Can you also help me create a legend based on the colour of the circle. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use appropriate values for `edge.arrow.size`. For me `1` works, but you may have to reduce it to `0.5` or less.

```
with(message, 
     plot(graph.data.frame(message), 
          vertex.color = sender_country,
          vertex.label.color = "white",
          edge.color = sender_country, 
          edge.arrow.width = 1, 
          edge.arrow.size = 1)
)
```

To add a legend just use `legend` and fill in the appropriate colors and labels. e.g.

```
legend('topright', legend = levels(message$sender_country), col = palette()[1:5], pch=16)
```