# group variables and color by type R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph where I need the vertices to be in name, with a different color due to the type of data (stock, forex and commodities)... I don't understand how to do it...

[image]

in this post [igraph group vertices based on community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693826/igraph-group-vertices-based-on-community) something similar is done... I need not circles, only letters and that they have a different color according to the type of data that is...

```r
library(Hmisc)                                        # For correlation matrix
library(corrplot)                                     # For correlation matrix
library("Spillover")
library(readxl)
library("xts")
library("zoo")    #
library("ggplot2")
library("nets")
library("MASS")
library("igraph")
library("reshape")    # For "melt" function/cluster network
library("writexl")


# We compute the dynamic interdependence. Direct edges denoted as Granger causality linkages
# We compute the contemporaneous interdependence. Indirect edges denoted as Partial correlation linkages
stock          <-  table[1:55, 1:55]
forex          <-  table[56:95, 56:95]
commodities    <-  table[96:116, 96:116] 

dim(stock); dim(forex); dim(commodities) 
View(stock); 
View(forex); 
View(commodities) 

# Full network
network.spill <- graph.adjacency(table, mode='directed')

degree   <- degree(network.spill)                                             # number of adjacent edges  
between  <- betweenness(network.spill)
close    <- closeness(network.spill, mode = "all")
autorsco <- authority.score(network.spill)$vector
eccentry <- eccentricity(network.spill, mode = "all")
measures <- cbind(as.matrix(degree), as.matrix(between), as.matrix(close), as.matrix(autorsco), as.matrix(eccentry))
View(measures)

V(network.spill)[which(network.spill_forex)]$color="red"
V(network.spill)$size <- round((degree-min(degree))/(max(degree)-min(degree)))       # To create vertex
V(network.spill)$shape <- "sphere"
E(network.spill)$name=1:116

# For stock returns layout_nicely(network.spill)
par(mfcol = c(1, 1))
plot( network.spill, layout = layout_nicely(network.spill), vertex.color = c("gold"), vertex.label.cex=0.6,
       vertex.size = autorsco*2,edge.curved = 0.2, edge.arrow.mode=0.5,edge.arrow.size=1.5)                      # To make the chart
```

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Your largest problem here is going to be overplotting (you can't read any of the text because they are all overlaid on each other). There may be a way to improve this substantially, as well as coloring according to the type of data, but we really need a reproducible example to help you here.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, now i added some more information... the overplotting its not a big trouble, i can solve that... i want to separate the data for type and coloring according that just as you say.... thanks a lot!!